# Existe algum atalho para ir para a última linha editada?

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

No Sublime Text, já aconteceu de eu estar editando uma linha do código e ter que verificar um código logo acima para conferir o que vou implementar. Acontece que, quando faço isso, sinto falta de um atalho para eu voltar para a linha que eu estava editando anteriormente.

Exemplo:

- Estou editando a linha 175 do aquivo
- Foquei na linha 22 para poder ver uma função declarada ali.
- Quero voltar prara linha 175 novamente, a qual eu estava editando.

Tem dois detalhes:

- Daria pra usar <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, mas eu sempre teria que gravar a linha que eu estava antes.
- Eu atualmente uso <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Quando ele foca na linha, eu dou <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. Isso é feio demais.

Tem algum atalho que foque na última linha que eu editei no Sublime Text 3?

Comment: sublime tem plugin de bookmark, serve exatamente pra isso

Comment: Já tentou `alt`+`-`?

Comment: @hkotsubo parece funcionar ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No Windows e Linux, você pode usar <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> ("alt" + "hífen"). No Mac OS o atalho é <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

Digitando várias vezes seguidas, ele vai voltando em todas as posições que o cursor estava, inclusive em abas diferentes (ele só não pula entre janelas diferentes, mas dentro da mesma janela, ele pula de uma aba para outra sem problemas).

Se quiser avançar em vez de voltar, use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (ou <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> no Mac OS).

Também é possível mudar as teclas de atalho editando o seu arquivo `.sublime-keymap` (menu *Preferences*->*Key Bindings*). Por exemplo, se eu quiser que <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> seja o atalho para voltar e <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> para avançar, basta adicionar:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+-"], "command": "jump_back" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+-"], "command": "jump_forward" },
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. +1